# Sinatra route regex constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sinatra

i rebuild a small rails (too overkill) app in sinatra. i have a route like this:

```
match 'verify/:name/:bundle/:license' => 'verify#index', :constraints => { :bundle => /.*/ }
```

how can i rebould it in sinatra in terms of the constraints attribute?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do it this way: (taken from [Sinatra's documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Routes))

```
get %r{/hello/([\w]+)} do
  "Hello, #{params[:captures].first}!"
end
```

Or inside the block itself:

```
get '/hello/:name' do
  raise Sinatra::NotFound unless params[:name].match /\w+/
  "Hello, #{params[:name]}!"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ruby 1.9, you can use named captures in a regex route, like so:

```
require 'sinatra'

get %r{verify/(?<name>\w+)/(?<bundle>.*)/(?<license>\w+)} do |name, bundle, license|
  # do stuff
end
```